# Como chamar um método ao utilizar o operador switchMap

Tags: angular, programação-funcional, rxjs, programação-reativa

Estou estudando formulários reativos, ao trabalhar com Framework `Angular`.

Pensando em programação funcional e reativa, estou escutando as mudanças de status do controle `cep`, então, primeiro utilizei o operador `distinctUntilChanged` onde somente ira emitir quando o valor for alterado, ou seja, teremos um evento emitido ao digitar o primeiro numero como `INVALID`, pois coloquei uma validação via regex onde é necessário ter no minimo 8 dígitos, então, quando digitado o oitavo numero será emitido um evento com o status `VALID`

```
this.formulario.get('endereco.cep').statusChanges
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(status => status === 'VALID' ?
      this.cepService.consultaCEP(this.formulario.get('endereco.cep').value)
      : empty())
  )
  .subscribe(dados => dados ? this.populaEnderecoForm(dados) : {});
```

Então utilizei o operador `switchMap`, para que somente seja feito o `subscribe` caso o status do controle `cep` seja `VALID` e seja retornado do método `consultaCEP` um `Observable`.

O código está funcional, porém, preciso chamar o método abaixo, mesmo que, o status do controle `cep` seja `INVALID`.

```
resetaEnderecoFormulario() {
  this.formulario.patchValue({
  endereco: {
    complemento: null,
    rua: null,
    bairro: null,
    cidade: null,
    uf: null
  }
});
```

}

Poderia fazer de outras formas, mas gostaria de uma ideia levando em conta programação funcional e reativa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir realizar a chamada do método `resetaEnderecoFormulario()`, fiz a seguinte alteração:

`this.formulario.get('endereco.cep').statusChanges
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(status => {
          this.resetaEnderecoFormulario();
          return status === 'VALID' ?
            this.cepService.consultaCEP(this.formulario.get('endereco.cep').value)
            : empty()
        })
      )
      .subscribe(dados => dados ? this.populaEnderecoForm(dados) : {});`

Ou seja, coloquei a logica do `switchMap`, dentro de chaves `{}`, e defini o retorno sendo o resultado da função `if`